# Dynamic columns fixed length with auto scroll

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using angular js 1.3 here. What I have is a modal up which when clicked adds an column to existing table, the name of the column is based upon the selection made in the modal. One can add as many columns here. All this works fine. What my issue is that I am not sure how to maintain fixed column width and scrolling.

The width of the column keeps decreasing when more columns are added and even the scrolling does not comes out properly.
Sorry the code is a lot so just posting some code together with jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/u1vbeos5/107/

```
 <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <colgroup>
        <col class="unique-id">
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="unique-id">Name #</th>
          <th contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="c in targetTable.columns" ng-model="c.label"></th>
          <!--<th class="view-next-set"><a href="#">...</a></th>-->
          <td class="center add-column"><a href ng-click="open()">+ Add Column</a></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in targetTable.rows">
          <td contenteditable="true" class=""></td>
          <td contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="column in targetTable.columns" ng-model="r[column.id]" ng-blur="!r.id? addNewRow(r[column.id], r): undefined"></td>
          <!--<td class="blank" colspan="2"></td>-->
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Also here is the image:

https://imgur.com/a/qCn1AO7

Answer (score 0):

So you can set a minimum width fot your `.table td` and `.table th`

```
.table td,
.table th {
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

And you can set the `overflow` of you `.panel-body` as `auto`:

```
.panel-body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u1vbeos5/116/

Comment: Scrolling works fine but not the width. 2 things here: The initial width of the columns is 2 big, secondly with min-width it does not work. You can see yourself. Keep adding about 10-12 columns and the with keeps decreasing. What I want is a constant width sat 50px initially and then when I click add column then also width should remain 50px.

Comment: So I added !important to the width, it did work that the width of the newer columns added remains constant. But one issue still remains. Initial column width if very wide and first 4-5 columns width is wide. See your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set min-width and max-width to **th** and oveflow: auto to **.panel-body**....
Check below CSS

```
.table th {
  max-width: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
.panel-body{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: The width part does not work unless you add important attribute. Also how can we set the width of inital columns. See my previous comment on the previous post.

Answer (score 0):

What I end up doing was to add the below classes to TD and Panel:

```
.fixed-width {
    min-width: 50px !important;    
    width: 50px !important;
 }

 .panel-body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```